# Foot Tingling with Clipless Pedals

Tags: shoes, clipless, cleat

I bought a new commuter bike (`Marin Muir Woods 29er`) and some clipless shoes that are "walkable" [`DZR Shoes 'Midnight'`](http://www.dzrshoes.com/midnight) so I don't have to carry bike cleats around with me.  However, when I ride I often get a tingling in the ball of my foot

What are the common causes for this?  I was thinking shoe may be too big (I wear 10.5 US and picked up size 45 EU for the new shoes) as my heel picks up easily while walking around. Others mentioned moving the cleat back, but it already is pretty far back in the shoe.  I read the cleat should ideally be directly under the ball of the foot, is that not correct?

Any other insights to help alleviate this tingling/numbness would surely be appreciated.

Comment: This problem can be in part due to one habitually forcing the foot forward, due to having previously used toe clips, or due to shoes that are too large or some such.

Comment: A walkable shoe is not going to be as stiff.  I like street shoes (no cleat) and big platform downhill pedals for commuting.

Comment: I quite often get tingling if i tie my clipless shoes too tight. However, loosening them may not be an option if they're already a little big!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the shoes seem a little too big, try some insoles. Start with the inexpensive ones you can find in a drugstore for $10. That will keep your foot from moving around inside the shoe without having to tighten the straps/laces so much. And maybe the extra cushion provided by the insoles will make the shoes feel a little more comfortable.

Comment: Seems like the problem went away after the shoes got more broken in.  Thanks for the assist!